# rails3 model redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called `User`. In the model I want to check if a value is true or false.
If the value is true then break all operations and redirect to a specific page.

How do I do that?

```
before_create :check_user

def check_user
    if User.find_by_email(self.email)
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and you never need to redirect form model.

You should do it in controller something like

```
before_filter :check_user
...
private
def check_user
  redirect_to root_path unless User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
before_create :check_user

def check_user
    unless User.find_by_email(email).nil?
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

See if this does what you want.